# Compare dataframe with database: insert new values, update changed values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been looking into other solutions but haven't found anything that shows what I'm trying to do. This is the structures of my data:

My database has these columns; id is the primary key, inserted_date is auto generated:

```
+----+------------+-------+---------------+
| id |   fruit    | price | inserted_date |
+----+------------+-------+---------------+
|  1 | apple      |     1 | 2023-22-01    |
|  2 | banana     |     2 | 2023-22-01    |
|  3 | strawberry |     3 | 2023-22-01    |
+----+------------+-------+---------------+
```

My dataframe has these columns:

```
+--------+-------+
| fruit  | price |
+--------+-------+
| apple  |     1 |
| banana |     4 |
| pear   |     2 |
+--------+-------+
```

At the end, this is what I would like to see in the database:

```
+----+------------+-------+---------------+
| id |   fruit    | price | inserted_date |
+----+------------+-------+---------------+
|  1 | apple      |     1 | 2023-22-01    | <- No change. In new dataframe
|  2 | banana     |     4 | 2023-22-01    | <- Updated
|  3 | strawberry |     3 | 2023-22-01    | <- No change. Not in new dataframe
|  4 | pear       |     2 | 2023-22-02    | <- New Value
+----+------------+-------+---------------+
```

I would get that data by comparing the "fruit" (unique value) with the price, which could change.

I already have the DataFrames setup with the data but haven't found a way to compare them and insert the correct data into the database. I can do it 1 by 1, but figured that there's a better way to do it. Appreciate any help!

Comment: `id` is a primary key? I suppose you don't want to override your existing table with all data? You want incremental update?

Comment: Correct. I wouldn't want to truncate and insert, unless it makes sense

Comment: How do you connect to your database (direct library, ORM like SqlAlchemy)? And what is your database (SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL)?

Comment: It's mssql. I'm using pd.read_sql_query to create a dataframe from the database

Comment: maybe you do a read_sql to get a mapping of ID to fruit (use a merge on the dataframe) then upload the dataframe to a temp table and use UPSERT?